# how i can get the row values by clicking button in that table using jquery magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, phtml

```
 <td data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("Quote Id")?>" class="col quoteid">
                                        <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quote->getId(); ?></span>
                                    </td>
```

[image]

> if I click on accept button, I want to get first row (value)
>
> here is I tried but I'm getting more empty spaces and ("\n") and (,)
>   like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
        $(document).on("click","#acceptnow", function(e) {
 var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
            var col1=currentRow.find(".quoteid").text();
            var col2=currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
            var col3=currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text();

}
```

> how i can get the values in proper ways (the values) in jquery magento 2

Comment: You can use trim() in javascript to remove empty spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
        $(document).on("click","#acceptnow", function(e) {
 var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
            var col1=currentRow.find(".quoteid").text().toString().trim();
            var col2=currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text().toString().trim();
            var col3=currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text().toString().trim();

}
```